# stop the keyboard popping up in html&javascript cordova app created in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, cordova, keyboard

I am trying to turn the keyboard that pops up in android app. I have a hex keypad to use instead of the google keyboard as entering a hex code 20 characters long with the normal android keyboard is trying.

Visual Studio uses a config.xml file to setup the Cordova side of the process, NOT a AndroidManifest.xml file.

I have setup the plugin cordova-plugin-keyboard but can't get the keyboard turned off using it.

Here is a copy of the config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.myappb763f9" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="en-US">
  <name>xxx-NCR</name>
  <description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.</description>
  <author href="xxxxx" email="xxxxx">xxxx</author>
  <vs:template-name>HTML</vs:template-name>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" height="44" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" height="71" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
  </platform>
  <vs:toolsetVersion>6.3.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
  <engine name="android" spec="~5.2.1" />
  <engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.0" />
  <engine name="windows" spec="~4.4.2" />
  <!--<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.2" />-->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.1" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
  <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="28" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="24" />
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True" />
  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-keyboard" spec="~1.2.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.2" />

  <!-- android -->
  <platform name="android">
    <js-module src="www/android/keyboard.js" name="keyboard">
      <clobbers target="window.Keyboard" />
    </js-module>
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="Keyboard">
        <preference name="HideKeyboard" value="true" />
      </feature>
    </config-file>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

I have removed my details. Is anyone able to help?  This question has been asked BUT not answered for cordova apps, I can stop it from coming up in Android Studio using Textviews instead of Edit text fields.

Comment: I forgot to say the app is written using HTM, CSS & Javascript ...not Java and xml so I really need a fix in one of those not Java or Xml. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched on Stack Overflow for days, to find a way to hide the android keyboard and got the answer from another forum.

USING HTML=

I used a button input type instead of text and now it works (no android keyboard and my hex keypad works).

```
<input type="button" id="MyValue" class="my-input" value="" placeholder="Enter Data">.
```

Java and XML:

I have used a TextView for the input instead of a EditText and no keyboard.